# 'On (the) closest Sunday' or 'on (the) nearest Sunday'

Tags: word-choice, articles

If I talk about the past, should I say 'on the closest Sunday' or 'on the nearest Sunday' (in relation to another point in the past), and should I use the article?

> [Something happened in the past]. On (the) nearest/closest Sunday, [something else happened].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging from your example I think the word you want is the 'next' Sunday.

> Something happened last month. On the next Sunday, something else happened.

If it were the nearest Sunday before the first thing happened, you would use the past perfect tense and say,

> Something happened two Sundays ago. On the previous Sunday, something else *had* happened.

You wouldn't need the article if you were talking about the nearest day relative to your own time frame.

> Something happened today. Next Sunday something else will happen.
> Something happened today. Last Sunday something else happened.

However, in your case you need to use both the preposition 'on' and the article because the Sunday you're talking about is not the nearest one relative to your own time frame. It is the nearest one relative to a day in the past.

Answer (score 1):

1. It probably sounds more natural to say "on the *past* Sunday" when referring to the Sunday that just passed.
2. Yes, the use of the definite article "the" is necessary. This is because you are referring to a specific Sunday. (see [section 3](https://depts.washington.edu/engl/askbetty/articles.php))